# Infinite summation of weighted exponential functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm looking for a closed-form expression for the following series
$$ \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty k^{-n j} \exp{\left(\frac{i t}{k^j}\right)}\,,$$
where $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\geq1$ and $k\geq2$.

Thanks!

Comment: What context is this in? Is there a reason you expect there to be a nice closed form? What have you tried so far, and is there any other information you think might be relevant?

Comment: It arises when calculating a cumulant generating function. I have tried changing the summation variable to $k^{-j} = l$ and plugging it into Mathematica (with all of the above assumptions), but to no avail. I do not expect it to have a closed form necessarily, but it would be useful if it has.